# File upload successfully but with 0 size bytes

Tags: protractor, jasmine-node, gulp-protractor

I'm able to upload file using below code

```
  var fileToUpload = 'tt.jpg';

    var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

    var FileDetector = require('selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js').FileDetector;
    browser.setFileDetector(new FileDetector());

    element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);`
```

But file will upload with zero byte size even though file size is actually 1 KB
[Fileupload successfully but with 0 size bytes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxEfv.png)

My development added below code for uploading the file
[Dev Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vPmH.png)

Comment: Hi, how do you think Protractor will influence this, or is this a real bug in your app? Did you also tried it with a bigger file, manually and with protractor?

Comment: When i do with manually, it work fine but not with Automation using protractor.

Comment: Do you have an example app where we can test it?

Comment: No i dont have app to test it

Comment: Then it will be hard to help you with this